# Generating SQL command / OS command injection vectors manually using http headers

Tags: security

Recently i was using the tools like burp, appscan for testing the web applications from security perspective. These tools uses the vector for finding the vulnerabilities in the web application. Few of those are observed to be using the http request headers to inject sql commands in encoded form. Is there any specific encoding that applies to SQL commands in such cases ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Appscan should pick up the http headers as test elements. Depend on your test policy, Appscan can apply a collection of injection attack patterns to each of the test elements.